# Kotlin + Mockito: getting a null

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Please I am a bit confused, this test fails with *"java.lang.IllegalStateException: notNull() must not be null"*:

```
@Test
fun when_resume_subscribe() {
    // WHEN
    presenter.onStart()
    // THEN
    verify<Model>(model).subscribe(notNull()) // <---- fails here
}
```

here is the method under test:

```
override fun onStart() {
    model.subscribe(object : Observer<Bar> {
        override fun onCompleted() {
            view?.showProgress(false)
        }
//... more stuff...
```

Please what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically casing the Null Object into the specific class object using Generic. The code as below, where we override any() to handle the issue accordingly.

```
private fun <T> any(): T {
Mockito.any<T>()
return uninitialized()
  }
private fun <T> uninitialized(): T = null as T
```

For more detail you can check this https://medium.com/@elye.project/befriending-kotlin-and-mockito-1c2e7b0ef791 tutorial.

Comment: Getting NPE while running androidTest. In case of unit test it runs fine. Not sure, if I am the only one facing the problem

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-kotlin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

will have the method `Mockito.anyOrNull()` which will not fail on non nullable arguments...